# How do I send the current timestamp as a String , over a networked connection(using Java)?

Tags: java, network-programming

I need to code a simple Java client/server pair, where the server sends the timestamp to any `N` number of clients. Here my code thus far, for the Server side (client is just the same type of code) :

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class EchoServer 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 

        try { 
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10007); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10007."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 

        Socket clientSocket = null; 
        System.out.println ("Waiting for connection.....");

        try
        { 
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            System.err.println("Accept failed."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 

        System.out.println ("Connection successful");
        System.out.println ("Waiting for input.....");

        //added in TimeStamp code
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        String timeString = (String)(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), 
                                      true); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
            new InputStreamReader( clientSocket.getInputStream())); 

        String inputLine; 

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
            System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 
            out.println(inputLine + timeString ); 

            if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) 
                break; 
        } 

        out.close(); 
        in.close(); 
        clientSocket.close(); 
        serverSocket.close(); 
    } 
}
```

I'm getting this error :

> \TimestampServer>javac *.java EchoServer.java:40: error: inconvertible
>   types
>       String newshit = (String)(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
>                                ^   required: String   found:    Timestamp 1 error

thanks

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Use `java.util.Date` (good), but send the value as an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date/time string.  This is the same format JSON and JAXB use.

Comment: you said that the server sends the timestamp to many client, so you need a threaded server.

Comment: @FoggyDay  - Ok, understood!  For some reason, when I ran the code Denis gave it returns just one long number like `12341238492312`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.valueOf(new Date().getTime())
```

Comment: I think afterwards, we need to convert to normal Date yes? it returns a big number like '12341238492312'

Comment: The problem is that different systems won't necessarily agree on "what the big number" actually means.  A "timestamp" is usually the #/seconds, or milliseconds - or whatever - from some ["epoch"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29): 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GM, Jan 1, 1900 - or whatever.  There are many different "timestamps": Unix dates, DOS file dates, NTFS file dates, etc. etc.  Using an ISO 8601 date/time string eliminates potential portability and/or timezone issues.

Comment: Yep, long value has no typing, but it is very simple and compact. And you need document somewhere that it is "unix timestamp in milliseconds". I would say it is good for internal API where you need maximum compression. For public API like REST it is better to always use ISO 8601

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would do the trick

```
 String timeString = new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString()
```